# Run length encode in C, Problem with strcat

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, strcat

I'm trying to write a run-length encoding program in C.

For the input 'ABBCD' I expect the following result: 'A1B2C1D1'

I hand over a two-dimensional char array line for line to the function that encodes the characters:

```
for(i; i <= curline; i++)    //hand over line for line
{
    encoded->lines[i] = malloc(255);
    encoded->lines[i] = rle_encode(read->lines[i]);   //read->lines contains the characters of each line
    printf("%s", encoded->lines[i]);  // print out the result returned by the function rle_encode
}
```

I have tested this and know that it would work.

Now this is my function rle_encode:

```
char *rle_encode(char *line){
char *encode = malloc(sizeof(2 * strlen(line) + 1));
char prev = line[0];   //here I want to save the previous character

int i = 0;
int z = 1;
do{
    i++;
    if(prev == line[i])     // if character n equals n-1 (previous)
    {
        z++;                // increase counter varaible z
    }else
        {
            strcat( encode, line[i] );      //the content of line[i] will be append to the array encode
            strcat( encode, z );   //also the counter variable will be appended
        }
    prev = line[i];

}while(line[i] != '\n');     //in the end of each line a '\n' appears, if line[i] is '\n' it should stop the function

return encode;}
```

What is wrong in function `rle_encode`?

Comment: plus your pointer `encode`is allocated wrong `sizeof (encode)` is equivalent to `sizeof(char*)`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Your code does not compile and it is incomplete. Please post real code. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve].

Comment: @joH1 thanks for your help, what is wrong with my return type?

Comment: @D.J.A.there _is_ no return type, that's what's wrong. It's incorrect C.

Comment: @OneManMonkeySquad thanks, I forgot that, I just updated the code

Comment: `if(prev = line[i])` hmm...

Comment: There are many issues in your (incomplete) code. If you want help, please do what I've asked in my previous comment and act accordingly.

Comment: @D.J.A. sorry, but about everything in your code is wrong. Compile with all warnings enabled and treat them as errors. Did you include `<string.h>`?. Both of your calls to `strcat` are wrong, `strcat(encode, line[i]);`: you're trying to concatenate a `char` to a `char*` which is wrong, and with `strcat(encode, z);` you try to concatenate an `int` to c `char*` which is wrong too, You probably need to start reading you C text book, especially the chapter dealing with strings and the one dealing with pointers and memory allocation.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes I include <string.h>

Comment: You are calling `strcat` on an uninitialized destination buffer. You should set `encode[0] = '\0';` before the `do {` loop.

Comment: @D.J.A.and you've got no warnings from the compiler? What is your platform? What is your compiler?

Comment: I understand. Is strcat the overall wrong function to use for my aim? What else could I use?

Comment: `strcat` is the wrong function to use anyway because you don't want to append strings, you want to append single characters followed by run counts.

Comment: @IanAbbott So which other function could I use to solve this problem?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I use geany and I receive the following warning messages:

Comment: 1-rle.c:19:25: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcat’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Comment: 1-rle.c:20:21: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcat’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Comment: You cannot use `strcat` to append an integer to a string buffer unless you first convert the integer into a string. You can use `sprintf` to write the run count to a specific place in the `encode` buffer, but you need to keep track of the current position in the `end` buffer so you can append the character and length to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
malloc(sizeof(encode))
```

sizeof(encode) is the size of a pointer, so you allocate for it only 4 or 8 bytes.

I think that you also have to start the counters i and z from 0, not from 1.

EDIT:
There are many problems, I did not mark them all.

Comment: thanks, I just changed sizeof(encode) to sizeof(char)

Comment: I want to know the number of char in  a row, so z has to start at 1

Comment: @D.J.A.: You know that `sizeof(char)` is 1, don't you? That's enough to hold the null terminator and nothing else. In the worst case, when there are no consecutive characters, you will need `2 * strlen(line) + 1` characters.

Comment: @D.J.A. To avoid the worst case allocation mentioned by @MOehm, you could do two passes. The first pass would work out the required buffer length. Then, after allocating the buffer, the second pass would fill it in. For doing it in a single pass, you need to allocate a buffer of sufficient size to handle the worst case, but you could call `realloc` to reduce the buffer size to the required size afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer to your question because there are many other issues in your code.

This small program shows how to append a `char` to a string and how to append the decimal representation of an `int` to a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char encode[100] = "abc";

  printf("%s\n", encode);

  // append the char 'X' to the encode string
  int len = strlen(encode);
  encode[len] = 'X';
  encode[len + 1] = 0;       // put the NUL terminator

  printf("%s\n", encode);

  // append the decimal representation of the int y to encode

  int y = 123;
  char *p = encode + strlen(encode);
  sprintf(p, "%d", y);

  printf("%s\n", encode);
}
```

Output:

```
abc
abcX
abcX123
```

You really need to learn the basics of C.